# The button freezes

Tags: button, javafx, freeze

I'm currently being asked to design a robot and give it a few capabilities by the technical college. One of these capabilities is that on a click on the Revive button, the robot will appear again (after having disappeared by right-clicking the robot itself three times!).

My code doesn't work though. On a click on the button it seems frozen and does not react anymore!

How can I fix this?

Here my code:

```
package at.ac.fhcampuswien;

import javafx.animation.FadeTransition;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;


public class HelloRobot extends Application {
    private int counter = 0;

    private static final int BOARD_SIZE = 600;
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        Group root = new Group();
        Group robot = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("robot.fxml"));
        root.getChildren().add(robot);

        Label label = new Label("");
        label.setPrefWidth(BOARD_SIZE);
        label.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        root.getChildren().addAll(label);

        Button revive = new Button("Revive!");
        revive.setOnAction(actionEvent -> {

            if(counter < 3) {
                label.setText("!Dead yet!?");
            } else {
                root.getChildren().add(robot);
                label.setText("Be nice this time");
                counter = 0;
            }
            /*
            for(Node node: root.getChildren()){
                if(robot != null)
                {
                    label.setText("!Dead yet!?");
                }
            }
            if(counter == 3) {
                root.getChildren().add(robot);
                label.setText("Be nice this time");
                counter = 0;
            }*/
        });
        root.getChildren().add(revive);

        robot.setOnMousePressed(mouseEvent -> {
            if (mouseEvent.isSecondaryButtonDown()) {
                if(counter == 0) {
                    label.setText("Oooooouch!");
                    counter++;
                }
                else if(counter == 1){
                    label.setText("Please no!");
                    counter++;
                }
                else if(counter == 2){
                    root.getChildren().remove(robot);
                    counter++;
                }
            }
        });

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, BOARD_SIZE, BOARD_SIZE);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello Robot");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

This is the robot.fxml file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.Group?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.shape.Circle?>
<?import javafx.scene.shape.CubicCurve?>
<?import javafx.scene.shape.Ellipse?>
<?import javafx.scene.shape.Polygon?>
<?import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle?>

<Group fx:id="robot" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="at.ac.fhcampuswien.RobotController">
   <children>
      <AnchorPane prefHeight="600.0" prefWidth="600.0">
         <children>
            <Polygon fill="#ff1f1f" layoutX="349.0" layoutY="425.0" points="-18.0, 47.0, 51.0, 47.0, 0.0, -60.0" stroke="BLACK" strokeType="INSIDE" />
            <Polygon fill="#ff1f1f" layoutX="247.0" layoutY="433.0" points="-47.0, 40.0, 25.0, 40.0, 8.0, -70.0" stroke="BLACK" strokeType="INSIDE" />
            <Rectangle arcHeight="5.0" arcWidth="5.0" fill="DODGERBLUE" height="200.0" layoutX="200.0" layoutY="163.0" stroke="BLACK" strokeType="INSIDE" width="200.0" />
            <Circle fill="#eaff1f" layoutX="300.0" layoutY="163.0" radius="100.0" stroke="BLACK" strokeType="INSIDE" />
            <Ellipse fill="#1eff3e" layoutX="264.0" layoutY="117.0" radiusX="36.0" radiusY="14.0" stroke="BLACK" strokeType="INSIDE" />
            <Ellipse fill="#1eff3e" layoutX="336.0" layoutY="117.0" radiusX="36.0" radiusY="14.0" stroke="BLACK" strokeType="INSIDE" />
            <Circle fill="DODGERBLUE" layoutX="300.0" layoutY="163.0" radius="22.0" stroke="BLACK" strokeType="INSIDE" />
            <CubicCurve controlX1="-57.0" controlX2="56.0" controlY1="41.0" controlY2="41.0" endX="56.0" fill="DODGERBLUE" layoutX="301.0" layoutY="203.0" startX="-57.0" stroke="BLACK" />
            <Polygon fill="DODGERBLUE" layoutX="170.0" layoutY="262.0" points="30.0, 30.0, 30.0, -34.0, -43.0, 0.0" stroke="BLACK" strokeType="INSIDE" />
            <Polygon fill="DODGERBLUE" layoutX="370.0" layoutY="265.0" points="30.0, 30.0, 30.0, -34.0, 103.0, -4.0" stroke="BLACK" strokeType="INSIDE" />
         </children>
      </AnchorPane>
   </children>
</Group>
```

Comment: I tried your code and everything looks fine to me. Is there any exception thrown?

Comment: Here is a Video (https://youtu.be/jbtSCvk7pBQ) where I'm trying your program out

Comment: Can you reproduce he issue, if you remove the `fx:controller` attribute from the fxml? So far everything seems fine, but some unconventional code in the controller could result in issues... (Ich hoffe auf Englisch zu kommunizieren stellt kein Problem für Sie dar. Andernfalls dürfte der Post auf dieser Seite wenig erfolgversprechend sein.)